# Python equivalent of matlabfrag

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, eps

I have been a regular user of matlab for plotting. I use `matlabfrag` to save as `eps` for the plot along with a `tex` file containing labels. This can be rendered with `Latex` fonts after including them in Latex document.

I have started using `python` recently. Is there any equivalent of `matlabfrag` for `python`? I am aware of `matplotlib2tikz` and not exactly looking for it.